# Solve using Hensel's lifting

Tags: number-theory

Find two integers $t_5 < 419^5 $ such that $t_5^2 \equiv 5 \pmod {419^5}$

My attempt: $f(x)=t_5^2-5$, hence, $f'(x)=2t_5$ and then I guess values for x for which $f'(x) \not\equiv 0 \pmod {419}$? I'm not really sure what to do after this step. Also is $t_5$ just a regular variable or does sub 5 mean something?

Answer (score 1):

Start by solving $x^2 \equiv 5 \mod 419$: you should get two solutions, say $a_1$ and $b_1$.  Now given $a_i$ and $b_i$ that solve $x^2 \equiv 5 \mod 419^i$, you find $a_{i+1}$ and $b_{i+1}$ that solve $x^2 \equiv 5 \mod {419}^{i+1}$, with $a_{i+1} \equiv a_i \mod 419^{i}$ and $b_{i+1} \equiv b_i \mod 419^i$.  If $a_{i+1} = a_i + 419^{i} t$, you want $a_i^2 + 2 a_i 419^i t \equiv 5 \mod 419^{i+1}$, which means $t \equiv (5 - a_i^2)/(2 \cdot 419^i a_i) \mod 419$.